# Why is my css not being applied?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple html file that I want to apply some css to change the look but the css is not being applied to my content.

I know that I should probably put the css in an external file but I am just learning from an example in a book right now.

Here is the html.  Can anyone help please?  Thanking you in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .content p{
        background-color:#C0C0C0;
        padding: 3px;
    }
    .heading p{
        display: inline;
        background-color:black;
        color: white;
        font-weight:bold;
        padding:3px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="heading">
        <p>Heading A</p>
        <p>Heading B</p>
        <p>Heading C</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Paragraph A</p>
        <p>Paragraph B</p>
        <p>Paragraph C</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.heading` selects items with a class of `heading`. You want `#heading` to select an item by id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are applying your style to a class, not an ID. Change  ID in HTML to class.

i.e. `<div class="heading">`

Comment: Thank you! I changed "id" to "class" and it works now.

Thanks for everyone's input!

Answer (score 3):

your css should be

`#` = `id` `.` = `class`

from

```
.content p{
    background-color:#C0C0C0;
    padding: 3px;
}
.heading p{
    display: inline;
    background-color:black;
    color: white;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px;
}
```

to

```
#content p{
    background-color:#C0C0C0;
    padding: 3px;
}
#heading p{
    display: inline;
    background-color:black;
    color: white;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px;
}
```

I would also add that `ids` should be unique on a page, meaning that you can't have more then one element with the same `id`, therefore its almost always better to use `classes` for styling.

Answer (score 1):

`.content p` matches

```
<div class="content">
    <p>Paragraph A</p>
    <p>Paragraph B</p>
    <p>Paragraph C</p>
</div>
```

what you are looking for are: `#content p`